# WebGL last attributes do not work in Chrome on Windows

Tags: javascript, attributes, shader, webgl

I have this code in my vertex shader:

```
in vec3 geometry;
in vec4 offset; // xyz - offset, w sizeFactor
in vec4 rotationQuad;
in vec2 textureCoord;
in vec2 textureNr;
in highp float faceNumber;
in vec4 lightMatrix1;
in vec4 lightMatrix2;
in vec4 lightMatrix3;
in vec4 lightMatrix4;
in vec4 lightMatrix5;
in vec4 lightMatrix6;
```

The last two attributes "lightMatrix5" and "lightMatrix6" are not working in Chrome on Windows. In Firefox all works fine also on Chrome with Ubuntu Linux.

When I change the order of the attributes, the last two defined stop working.
E.g:

```
in vec4 lightMatrix1;
in vec4 lightMatrix2;
in vec4 lightMatrix5;
in vec4 lightMatrix6;
in vec4 lightMatrix3;
in vec4 lightMatrix4;
```

Now the "lightMatrix3" and "lightMatrix4" do not work but the "lightMatrix5" and "lightMatrix6" work fine now.

The Parameters from WebGL look like this:

```
WebGLInfo::: WebGL 2 supported
WebGLInfo::: Max Vertex Attributes 16
WebGLInfo::: Max Varying Vectors 32
WebGLInfo::: Max Vertex Uniform Vectors 1024
WebGLInfo::: Max Fragment Uniform Vectors 1024
```

Possible attributes should be 16, I'm using 12 and the limit seams to be 10?

Any idea why it happens and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the 4 vec4 (lightmatrix1-4) attributes with one mat4 attribute and it is working now. The attributes count seams to matter.